# How to setup Selenium testing environment in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, selenium

I have just switched from Windows to Ubuntu. I want to set up a Selenium testing environment. I got the eclipse setup but not getting Selenium IDE for Firefox browser which is compatible with Ubuntu. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Does this help: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-button/

Comment: It is giving message  "This add-on is not compatible with your version of Firefox."

Comment: Yes that would be a problem, what version of firefox are you using?

Comment: I am using 57.0 (64-bit) version

Comment: Oh unfortunately this is the latest version so you may have to wait a bit to get the plugin owners to update it